# Why would php not be able to talk to a local sql data base?

Tags: php, mysql

If I understand ports correctly they are used for mapping multiple locations on a remote machine. However if mysql and php are both on the same host computer then why or for what purpose would a port serve? For example I connect to mysql on localhost everything works fine but if i change mysql's port to 01 for example it stops working even localy... as there is no external networking involved why would this be the case??

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to occupy a single definite port, regardless of whether the MySQL server is running on the same machine or a different machine. It will

-Keep the other ports free

-Help the application communicate with the Databases securely, with flexibility.

-If there are multiple database servers running, it is always better that each run on a unique port to avoid collisions. For this you or your application need to know the designated port.